# Cannot figure out why VBA code is not entering the If statement

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to sort through accounts in two separate worksheets ("Participaciones Bond" and "Participaciones VAL") and copy the customers that are in both sheets into one column in worksheet "resumen" and the customers that are in one, but not the other, into another column in "resumen".

The part that copies those customers in both sheets works well, but I cannot figure out why the second if statement does not work.

```
'Patribond= i, patriVal= j
i = 5
j = 5
Do While Worksheets("Participaciones Bond ").Cells(i, "A") <> ""
    j = 5
    Do While Worksheets("Participaciones VAL ").Cells(j, "A") <> ""
        If Worksheets("Participaciones Bond ").Cells(i, 1).Value = Worksheets("Participaciones VAL ").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
            Worksheets("Participaciones Bond ").Activate
            Sheets("Participaciones Bond ").Select
            Worksheets("Participaciones Bond ").Rows(i).Copy Sheets("Resumen").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Exit Do
        End If
        j = j + 1

        'personas en patribond que no aparecen en patrival'
        If Worksheets("Participaciones VAL ").Cells(j, 1) = "" Then
            Worksheets("Resumen").Activate
            'Cells(3, "H").Value = "We got into the second IF"'
            Worksheets("Participaciones Bond ").Activate
            Range(Cells(i, "A"), Cells(i, "E")).Copy
            Worksheets("Resumen").Activate
            Range(Cells(i, "G"), Cells(i, "X")).Select
            Worksheets("Resumen").Paste
        End If
    Loop
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: do you need to rest `j`?

Comment: I believe I do need to reset J every time as it is a nested DoWhile loop. Side note - my data begins at row 5

Comment: No worries. I suspect it has something to do with that because I never get into the second if.

Comment: it's inside a loop that's controlled by the logic `Cells(j, "A") <> ""` so i think you're leaving the loop, i think you need `goto` rather than `exit do`

Comment: or put your if bit where the `exit do` is

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I would not advise the use of `GoTo` for anything other than error handling. There are better ways to find duplicates. I'm sure this sort of question has been asked before, but I'm struggling to find them...

Comment: i'd loop the 1st sheet and use countif/find/match on the 2nd sheet maybe

Comment: @ByronPop Do you need to find uniques from **both** worksheets, or only from one?

Comment: Both worksheets would be ideal.

Comment: The code appears to be copying "matching" data to the end of the "Resumen" sheet, but unmatched values are being copied to the same row in the "Resumen" sheet as the row they exist on in the "Participaciones Bond " sheet - is that the intention?

Comment: That is what is happening. Ideally I would like to copy the unmatched values as the row they exist on in the "Participaciones sheet to the "resumen" sheet in the same format, but a few rows over, but I haven't done that yet. I believe it would be -                                      Worksheets("Participaciones Bond ").Rows(i).Copy Sheets("Resumen").Range(Cells(i + 1, "G"), Cells(i + 1, "X"))

Comment: 5 columns to 18 columns, as you currently have, would copy once - to G:K.  If you tried copying 5 columns to 20 columns, e.g. A:E to G:Z, it would copy 4 times.  But you can't copy an entire row into just 18 columns.

Comment: @ByronPop I don't think that would work, you can't copy a row into a limited cell range. You would have to use `Worksheets("Participaciones Bond ").Range(Cells(i, "A"), Cells(i, "E")).Copy Sheets("Resumen").Range(Cells(i + 1, "G"), Cells(i + 1, "X"))`

Comment: Are you sure that the second `If` is not being entered - are you sure it isn't just copying the data and then subsequent matched information is overwriting it?  Have you tried putting a `MsgBox` inside the `If` to say whether you get into it?  Or step through your code and watch what it is doing as it does it.

Comment: @yowE3K thank you!. I am getting into the for loop it turns out.

Comment: @SteveES However, the copy and paste code gives me a                                                                   Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: @Byron Pop: That error could have multiple causes, but particularly, it happens when you try to copy an entire Row and paste it into a cell which is not in the first column. Let's say you're trying to copy the entire row 24 into cell "G24", for example. See my answer for a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which data you have for testing, but I think that your code is working just fine, that is: it is entering both If conditions. But the way you check it is by writing into a cell ("H3") that is probabily overwritten when you copy an entire row with the instruction

```
 with Worksheets("Participaciones Bond ").Rows(i).Copy Sheets("Resumen").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

This is how I would do it.

You don't need to change selection nor to activate worksheets in order to copy from / to them.

Also, I would copy in the same way both times, for records in both sheets and for records only in the first sheet, not copying the entire row, but limiting the source to the range containing the data. This way you won't accidentally overwrite the columns to the right of the sheet. And your records will get copied at the top of the "Resumen" sheet, too.

In order to do so, I changed

```
  Rows(i).Copy.
```

to

```
  Range("A" & i, "E" & i).Copy.
```

I also added references to the three sheets though it isn't necessary.

```
Dim wBond           As Worksheet
Dim wVal            As Worksheet
Dim wRes            As Worksheet

Set wBond = Worksheets("Participaciones Bond ")
Set wVal = Worksheets("Participaciones Val ")
Set wRes = Worksheets("Resumen")

i = 5
Do While Not IsEmpty(wBond.Cells(i, "A"))
    j = 5
    Do While Not IsEmpty(wVal.Cells(j, "A"))

        If wBond.Cells(i, 1).Value = wVal.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
            '   La persona está en ambas hojas: copiar en la columna correspondiente
            wBond.Range("A" & i, "E" & i).Copy wRes.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Exit Do
        End If

        j = j + 1

        If IsEmpty(wVal.Cells(j, 1)) Then
            wBond.Range("A" & i, "E" & i).Copy wRes.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If

    Loop
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Don't hard code `1048576` as the bottom of the worksheet, use `Rows.Count`

Comment: @SteveES yes, thanks! I worked on the given code and didn't give it much tought

Answer (score 0):

I started writing this code before dinner and got stuck. Now I am well fed but the thread may have progressed beyond what I was doing. Basically, I went by your description and wrote my own code. It's a different approach from the one you took, but then I got stuck on the meaning of your second IF and couldn't figure it out. Please run my code on your data and tell me if its worth continuing.

The code runs through all your names on the Bond sheet and copies data to the Resumen sheet. If a duplicate is found in the Val sheet it copies 10 columns of the Val data (I wonder, is this a logical error) to column A, else it copies 10 columns of data from the Bond sheet (I think both are the same and therefore I would prefer to copy all from the Bond sheet) to column K. The code is simpler than yours and therefore easier to tweak. Take a look. Test it on your data and see what you get.

```
Sub CopyCustomers()
    ' 06 Apr 2017

    Dim WsBond As Worksheet
    Dim WsVal As Worksheet
    Dim WsRes As Worksheet
    Dim Rl As Long                          ' WsBond last row
    Dim R As Long                           ' WsBond row
    Dim Rv As Long                          ' found row in WsVal
    Dim Rr As Long                          ' next row in WsRes
    Dim Cr As Long                          ' column in WsRes
    Dim Cust As String                      ' customer name from WsBond
    Dim Rng As Range                        ' range to be copied to WsRes

    Set WsBond = Sheets("Participaciones Bond ")
    Set WsVal = Sheets("Participaciones VAL ")
    Set WsRes = Sheets("Resumen")

    Rr = 5
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With WsBond
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For R = 5 To Rl
            Cust = .Cells(R, 1).Value
            Rv = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            Rv = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cust, WsVal.Columns(1), 0)
            ' no need to copy the entire row of 140K cells (takes too much time)
            ' in each of the following rows 10 stands for 10 columns being copied
            If Err = 0 Then
                Set Rng = WsVal.Range(WsVal.Cells(Rv, 1), WsVal.Cells(Rv, 10))
                Cr = 1                      ' paste to column A
            Else
                Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(R, 1), .Cells(R, 10))
                Cr = 11                     ' paste to column K
            End If
            Rng.Copy Destination:=WsRes.Cells(Rr, Cr).Resize(1, 10)
            Rr = Rr + 1
            Err.Clear
        Next R
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

There might be names in the Val sheet which are not in the Bond sheet. They would be easy to add but that would take another loop, not another IF. You might also not like the arrangement of rows in the Resumen sheet. Easy to tweak. I suppose you might be able to do it yourself. You don't want 10 column, you don't want column A, you don't agree with column K - all easy to adjust. I will be glad to help if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your data have headers in row 4, you could exploit `Autofilter()` and go like follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim commonRng As Range, uniqueBondRng As Range, uniqueValRng As Range

    GetCommonAndUniqueData "Participaciones Bond", "Participaciones VAL", commonRng, uniqueBondRng
    GetCommonAndUniqueData "Participaciones VAL", "Participaciones Bond", commonRng, uniqueValRng

    If Not commonRng Is Nothing Then commonRng.Copy Worksheets("Resumen").Range("a1")
    If Not uniqueBondRng Is Nothing Then uniqueBondRng.Copy Worksheets("Resumen").Range("B1")
    If Not uniqueValRng Is Nothing Then uniqueValRng.Copy Worksheets("Resumen").Range("C1")        
End Sub

Sub GetCommonAndUniqueData(sht1Name As String, sht2Name As String, commonRng As Range, uniqueRng As Range)
    Dim cell As Range

    With Worksheets(sht1Name)
        With .Range("A4", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=GetValues(sht2Name), Operator:=xlFilterValues
            With .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 0 Then Set commonRng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
                If commonRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set uniqueRng = .Cells
                Else
                    Set uniqueRng = .Cells(.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Resize(1)
                    For Each cell In .Cells
                        If Intersect(commonRng, cell) Is Nothing Then Set uniqueRng = Union(uniqueRng, cell)
                    Next
                    Set uniqueRng = Intersect(uniqueRng, .Cells)
                End If
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub


Function GetValues(shtName As String) As Variant
    With Worksheets(shtName)
        GetValues = Application.Transpose(.Range("A5", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value)
    End With
End Function
```